# Проблема с сохранением массива

Tags: swift, coredata

Есть идея но не знаю возможно ли ее реализовать. При добавлении результата, в CoreData сохраняются два значения Float(часы/минуты) и NSDate(дата добавления результата). Как сложить добавленные часы за месяц? 
Даже если часы/минуты и дату хранить как NSDate, есть ли методы разбивать всё по месяцам/годам? Есть же какие-то способы для отображения статистики.

PS Как вариант, часы можно добавлять в отдельный массив и отображать  как сумму всех значений массива, также название месяца присвоить другой переменной . Задать условие при добавлении результата, например если текущая дата(месяц) добавления отличается от переменной(с названием месяца), то удалить все из массива и добавить новое значение.

UPD

В теле функции добавления результата написал код. Выше идею я описал, вот часть кода:

```
@IBAction func wTime() {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        tMoney = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WorkTime", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! WorkTime

        ///Работа с пикерами

        let deltaYesterdayDate = yesterdayDate.date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(addTime) //второй пикер минус время

        ///нахождение разницы во времени
        let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Month, .Hour, .Minute], fromDate: todayDate.date, toDate: deltaYesterdayDate, options: .WrapComponents)

        ///результаты
        let diffHour = Int(components.hour) //Часы

        let diffMinute = Int(components.minute) ///Минуты

        //текущий месяц из результата
        let monthResult = (components.month)


        //Массив для часов
        var arrayHours = [Int]()

        let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("settings")

        //переменная для условия сравнения месяца
        var monthWas = Int(tMoney.currentMonth!)
       //переменная для первого запуска т.к. при первом запуске currentMonth не имеет значения в CoreData
    var firstLaunch = 0
    //первое условие по идее должно выполняться только один раз
    if firstLaunch == 0 && monthWas != monthResult {

        let hourForArray = diffHour * 60
        arrayHours.append(hourForArray)
        arrayHours.append(diffMinute)

        } 
        ///это условие выполняется если сохраненный месяц равен месяцу,который берется из DatePicker
         else if monthWas == monthResult {

            let hourForArray = diffHour * 60
            arrayHours.append(hourForArray)
            arrayHours.append(diffMinute)

        } 
           //если результат добавляется в новом месяце
            else if monthResult > monthWas {

            tMoney.currentMonth = Int(monthResult) //добавить новое значение в CoreData
            arrayHours.removeAll() //очистить массив
            let hourForArray = diffHour * 60
            arrayHours.append(hourForArray)
            arrayHours.append(diffMinute)
        }
        //если месяц добавления равен 1(например январь 2017)
        else if monthResult < monthWas && monthWas == 12 {

            tMoney.currentMonth = Int(monthResult)
            arrayHours.removeAll()
            let hourForArray = diffHour * 60
            arrayHours.append(hourForArray)
            arrayHours.append(diffMinute)

        }


        //сумма элементов массива
        var sumHours = Float(arrayHours.reduce(0, combine: +))

        //общее кол-во денег для отображения за месяц
        var sumMoneyForMonth = Float(sumHours * (settings/60))
        var summoneyAll = Float(sumMoneyForMonth - (sumMoneyForMonth * 0.13))


        tMoney.allTime = Float(sumHours)

        tMoney.allMoney = Float(summoneyAll)

        tMoney.currentMonth = Int(monthResult)

        appDelegate.saveContext()
       }
```

Проблема состоит в том что элементы добавленные в массив не сохраняются. Как сделать так чтобы они сохранялись и удалялись при необходимости?